# VS 2013 Unspecified Error when I try to Get Latest Changes (Recursively)

Tags: visual-studio-2013

For the past few months I am unable to right-click and run Get Latest Changes (Recursively) from within VS 2013 Update 4 projects.  I am able to Get Latest when I run Get Latest Version within Source Code Explorer. I am also able to check in my changes without concern.
This was happing within Update 3 and well now in Update 4.
There are no messages other than the Unspecified Error dialog message. 
I am using Visual Studio Online for my TFS repository.

Cheers

Comment: Have a look in the event logs on the TFS Application Server.

Answer (score 0):

Well as it turned out, the issue was related to an older version of [nodejstools](http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/).  I just happen to update to the latest RC version and the issue is gone.

BTW, NodeJSTools is awesome... I am having lots of fun building a TypeScript to DART transformer that runs in Node, built in TypeScript.